# .pdf form submit as HTML - how to handle response in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, pdf

I have designed a .pdf form (using Acrobat Pro DC).

I use a JavaScript action attached to a button to verify that required fields are filled in, and submit the form using `this.submitForm({"cURL": <my_url>, "cSubmitAs": "HTML"})`.

I have a PHP script which receives the data in $_POST, and I have verified that this is working properly.

However - after I open the form in Adobe Reader XI, fill it out, and submit it - it pops up a pair of scary-looking security warning windows:

[image]
[image]

This is just the result page from my PHP script - Reader saves it as a temporary file and displays it - but it's going to scare the bejeezus out of three-quarters of my users, and the page doesn't actually say anything useful anyway besides "yes, that worked".

I want some sort of response - I don't want invisible failures - but this is ridiculous. If my JavaScript could just get a pass-or-fail return value I could handle it from there, but I don't see any way to do that. Ideas?

Comment: whar are you doing in the end of your php? Saving to a file and returning that? Or any redirect?

Comment: It appends the data to a Google spreadsheet and returns "OK". I tried returning nothing at all, ie a blank page, but that made no difference.

Comment: I found this article http://khkonsulting.com/2017/08/connect-database-pdf-form-time-without-soap/ which suggests submitting the form as XFDF instead - apparently this takes more processing on the back-end but gives more control over the process and can pass information back to the form. It still puts up a security warning, but a less threatening-looking one. I am going to try implementing this.